# Permission Denial: opening provider com.miui.gallery.provider.GalleryOpenProvider

Tags: android, inputstream, android-bitmap, xiaomi

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.miui.gallery.provider.GalleryOpenProvider from ProcessRecord{932688f 12849:mobi.hubbler.app/u0a158} (pid=12849, uid=10158) that is not exported from uid 10034

```
    InputStream is = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(bitmapUri);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
```

trying to get bitmap from uri. This issue is happening only with MI(xiaomi) devices.

Comment: How are you getting `bitmapUri`?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType(IMAGE_MIME_TYPE);

Comment: Is the code in your answer in `onActivityResult()`?

Comment: This is the code in onActivityResult

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if(data!=null) {
                Uri bitmapUri = data.getData();
            }
        }
    }

Comment: this code working in all devices except MI(xiaomi) note 5 pro

Comment: That code does not do anything. You set a local `bitmapUri` value, then leave. Your error feels like you are passing the `Uri` to another activity or service, or you are saving it somewhere (file, database, `SharedPreferences`). You can only use this `Uri` in the original activity that requested it, or in another activity or service if you use `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`. See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) for more.

Comment: I am also getting this error, can somebody give the exact solution, this is happening only on Mi devices

Answer (score -3):

android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Welcome on SO! Can you add some explanation ?