# Android: Uri Access Life Time from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, android-permissions

I have a helper method for choosing images and videos, let's call it `Activity B`.

So, this is how it works:

```
// were in Activity A
// user wants to choose a video
startActivityB(callbacks);

------------------------------------

// were in Activity B now

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("video/*");
chooseVideoLauncher.launch(intent);

------------------------------------

// were in chooseVideoLauncher now
Uri videoURI = ...;
callbacks.passVideoURI(videoURI); // this way, Activity A gets the videoURI

// do some more things...

finish(); // so the helper activity B is finished now, as the video is chosen already


------------------------------------

// were in activity A again, but now we have the videoURI
// user clicked a button: "Upload video"
uploadVideo(videoURI);
```

This is the error I get:
`java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.miui.gallery.provider.GalleryOpenProvider from ProcessRecord{f5899ab 29899:com.xxx} (pid=xxx, uid=xxx) that is not exported from UID xxx`

I have googled the error and found this SO thread: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412179/permission-denial-opening-provider-com-miui-gallery-provider-galleryopenprovide)

@CommonsWare explains the error in a comment and links his blog post: [Uri Access Lifetime: Shorter Than You Might Think](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html)

---

So the error happens because the helper `Activity B` chose the file, so the access is tied to `Activity B`. No other activity has access, and as soon as `Activity B` is destroyed (what happens in my code), the access to `videoURI` is completely gone. So when I later try to upload the video, it throws this error.

I tried these solutions:

1. Create a local copy of the video and pass that copy to `Activity A`. This works, but is a bad solution. For longer videos the app crashes with a memory overflow. So it's not an option.
2. Setting the flags @CommonsWare mentioned. So the code looks like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
chooseVideoLauncher.launch(intent);
```

But this doesn't seem to change anything. The error message remains exactly the same. Am I setting them wrong?

---

@CommonsWare says using a service would also be a solution. I would prefer not to create a service purely for fixing this permission error. If there's no other solution, I will of course.

But is there no way to grant `Activity A` permission to that Uri as well?

Comment: why do you need 2 activities for this ?

Comment: `But this doesn't seem to change anything. ` Of course not. You cannot grant anything there yourself. What you could try instead is use these flags where you pass the obtained uri to the next activity.

Comment: If you want to stick to this two activities construct then do not use ACTION_PICK but ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT as then you can take persistable uri permission at obtaining the uri.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution, by far, is to combine Activity A and Activity B into a single activity. Use fragments or composables for separate screens.

> Setting the flags @CommonsWare mentioned. So the code looks like this:

You would not set the flags on the `ACTION_PICK` `Intent`. Instead, Activity B needs to start Activity A (in addition to `finish()`). You would put the `Uri` into the "data" facet of the `Intent` (e.g., via `setData()`), and you would put the flags on *that* `Intent`. You would also need something like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` or something to avoid having two copies of Activity A on the back stack.

Answer (score 0):

For the second way Set the flags to get the long lifetime, you can try to add the following code, to get the permission, then start the activity

```
val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
// Check for the freshest data.
contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)
```

Comment: This is not available for `ACTION_PICK`.